# Send to email address saved in cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the below VBA code to send Outlook email.

The email should be sent based on the condition applied on column "D".

If the condition is true on Column "D" the email should be created and sent to the email address in Column "C" where its cell is in the same row of the condition on column "D".

I have written all the codes except the code related to sending it to the email address in Column "C" within the same row of the condition on column "D".

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "You have pending quotation which its number" 
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to send the email to a recipient specified in the Excel sheet. To get this working you need to extract a value from the cell and pass it to the `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` method:

```
 Dim xRg As Range
    'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
      Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target)
        If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
            Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target.Cells("C2"))
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Dim value as string)
        Dim xOutApp As Object
        Dim xOutMail As Object
        Dim xMailBody As String
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "You have pending quotation which its number" 
        On Error Resume Next
        With xOutMail
            .To = value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "send by cell value test"
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set xOutMail = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

You may find a lot of samples on the [Mail from Excel with Outlook (Windows)](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) page. Pay special attention to the [Mail a different file(s) to each person in a range](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm) article.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: @ Eugene Astafiev, Yes I have tried to debug , and the error happened on the below line : Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Dim value as string)

Comment: Make sure a string is passed to the method.

Comment: @  Eugene Astafiev , what does that mean ? how I do it ?

Comment: The method accepts a string `Dim value as string`. So, you need to be sure a string is passed there. Did you try to debug the code? What value does `Target.Cells("C2")` return?

Comment: @ Eugene Astafiev , it gives me empty value , it doesn't work at all .

Comment: It seems you need to use an appropriate cell with an actual email address.

Comment: I had already used Column C which contains the emails address

Comment: Then you need to pass appropriate value to the method.

Answer (score 0):

To reference another cell based on a target cell.

`Target.Offset(0, -1)`

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Dim xRg As Range

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D2:D1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target.Offset(0, -1).Value)
    End If
    
End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(valueColC As String)

    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "You have pending quotation which its number"
    
    ' feel free to remove when it immediately precedes With xOutMail
    ' https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#On_Error_Resume_Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = valueColC
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```